# Git diff - path is outside repository

Tags: c#, git

I would like to execute a git diff command. The following command results in an 'fatal - path is outside repository' error. It is implemented in a C# application, using the Process class.

> git diff HEAD -- "Folder\TestFile.cs" >
>   "C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpEA7C.diff"
>
> fatal: C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpEA7C.diff:
>   C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpEA7C.diff is outside repository.

The command 'works', because I could successfuly execute it in a command prompt (cmd).

Could you explain what is wrong with the command and how to solve it in the C# application?

Comment: Not a windows guy at all, but: `git diff  HEAD -- Folder\TestFile.cs` uses relative paths, so maybe when you run it from command line you are in a relevant directory, but when doing it within your app it's not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to redirect standard output to a file.  Redirection is handled by the *shell*, and the `Process` class does not support it.  Instead, it's passing the `> C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpEA7C.diff` to the git process.  That's why git is complaining that the path `C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpEA7C.diff` is not in a repository.

If you're invoking a process and want to read its standard output, it's your responsibility to do that.

You can capture the output with the `Process` class.  For example:

```
var proc = new Process {
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo {
        FileName = "git.exe",
        Arguments = "diff HEAD -- "Folder\TestFile.cs"",
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        CreateNoWindow = true
    }
};

proc.Start();

while (!proc.StandardOutput.EndOfStream) {
    var line = proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
}
```

Of course, you could also use [LibGit2Sharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/LibGit2Sharp/0.25.0-preview-0073) and not have to worry about process creation and screen scraping the output.